# How can I get individual amounts of stock levels for multiple articles in 1 SQL statement

Tags: sql

I was wondering if it is possible to get 1 sql statement for my stocklevels of my different articles instead of doing that for all parts individually. This, to reduce the amount of communication with the server and to be more efficient.

The starting point is the next statement:

```
 SELECT SUM(STOCKIN.QUANTITY)- SUM(STOCKOUT.QUANTITY)
 FROM STOCKIN
   INNER JOIN STOCKOUT ON STOCKIN.FK_LOT=STOCKOUT=FK_LOT
 WHERE FK_LOT = 123456789
```

This gives of article 123456789 the difference between the 2 tables (StockIN and StockOUT). This is the stock level.

```
 SELECT SUM(STOCKIN.QUANTITY)- SUM(STOCKOUT.QUANTITY)
 FROM STOCKIN 
   INNER JOIN STOCKOUT ON STOCKIN.FK_LOT=STOCKOUT=FK_LOT
 WHERE FK_LOT IN (1234567,4567,654321,2345)
```

This one gives the difference between the tables (stockIN and StockOUT) of a couple of articles combined. The result will be 1 number.

What I am looking for is the amount fo stock for each article in 1 SQL:

```
1234567 = A
4567 = B
654321 = C
2345 = D
```

Is that possible or do I have to execute the first SQL a lot of times for all the different articles?

EDIT: ( I do not know if I have to do it like this on this forum or if I may use the reply button.... I know, on tis forum, the moderation is strickt..)

I have added GROUP BY and that works. But....

Other Strange things happens:
I understand that the below SQL is not logical but it is a reduction of my initial SQL.. IT just gives a strange result and therefore my big sql goes wrong....

Even when reducing the SQL to:

```
SELECT  
SUM(R_STOCKIN.QUANTITY)
From R_STOCKIN INNER Join R_STOCKOUT ON R_STOCKIN.FK_LOT=R_STOCKOUT.FK_LOT 
WHERE R_STOCKIN.FK_LOT =1350
```

Gives a different result as:

```
SELECT sum(QUANTITY)
  FROM [Speeltuin].[dbo].[R_STOCKIN] WHERE FK_LOT = 1350
```

It is a bigger number but he does not add the QUANTITY of the STOCK out table... I can not find out what he is doing.

Sum of stock in: 144

Sum of stock out: 122

Result of combined query: 864..
Anybody an idea?

It probably has to do with the fact that in STOCKOUT also a key FK_STOCKIN exists.
Stockout has 6 result and stockin has 2 results.. HE combines it to 12 results.

But, how to overcome this? Anybody an idea?

Does it need to be done without the JOIN statement? If yes, how?

Comment: You want `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT FK_LOT, SUM(STOCKIN.QUANTITY)- SUM(STOCKOUT.QUANTITY)
FROM STOCKIN 
  INNER JOIN STOCKOUT ON STOCKIN.FK_LOT=STOCKOUT.FK_LOT
WHERE FK_LOT IN (1234567, 4567, 654321, 2345)
GROUP BY FK_LOT
```

**Edit:** Do a `UNION ALL` instead, use negative QUANTITY values for STOCKOUT. `GROUP BY` the result:

```
select FK_LOT, SUM(QUANTITY)
from
(
  select FK_LOT, QUANTITY from STOCKIN
  UNION ALL
  select FK_LOT, -QUANTITY from STOCKOUT
) dt
group by FK_LOT
```

Comment: Really?, that simple but so powerful.. Nice.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have made an EDIT. If you can have a look, would be great..I got stuck on the JOIN....

Comment: Great, THANKS A LOT. Now, I am trying to understand but it works. I put the WHERE statement in it  and it workes like a charm.. I do not understand what "dt" is doing there but I am going to read about the UNION command.... Sorry, a bit new to SQL..

Comment: dt is just a table alias, a name for the subquery (_derived table_.)